# How to match exactly one string when there are multiple matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to extract from a file with 3-4 entries only the first journal reference. Any ideas on how to get only the first occurrence of a match?

Here is what I have done so far. I can extract the references, but I am getting all of them:

```
if file_line =~ /^  JOURNAL  \*?(.*)/
  captured_journal = $1
```

To be more clear, this is some of the file I am trying to extract only the first JOURNAL entry from:

```
  JOURNAL   Genomics 33 (2), 229-246 (1996)
  PUBMED   8660972
REFERENCE   2  (bases 1 to 17009)
  AUTHORS   Lopez,J.V.
  TITLE     Direct Submission
  JOURNAL   Submitted (07-FEB-1995) Jose V. Lopez, Laboratory of Viral
           Carcinogenesis, PRI/DynCorp, Biological Carcinogenesis and
            Development Prog, Bldg 560, Room 11-21, NCI-Frederick Cancer
           Research and Development Center, Frederick, MD 21702-1201, USA`enter code here`
```

I only want `"Genomics 33 (2), 229-246 (1996)"` but I am also getting the next JOURNAL entries.

Comment: @astropanic Can you at least provide a link to the relevant piece of the manual please?

Comment: I totally failed to understand the problem - what is the input? what is the expected output? what is the actual output?

Comment: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/detect

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer your question, your example does not show the complete coding.

One possibility: Your `if file_line` is inside a loop. Then you could leave the loop:

```
filecontent.each_line{|file_line|
  if file_line =~ /^  JOURNAL  \*?(.*)/
    captured_journal = $1 
    break
  end
}
```

As an alternative you could check, if you already found an entry:

```
captured_journal = nil
filecontent.each_line{|file_line|
  if file_line =~ /^  JOURNAL  \*?(.*)/
    captured_journal = $1 unless captured_journal
  end
}
```

But maybe you are not in a loop and the file content is stored in a String (e.g. with `File.read`). Then you could use a simple regex:

```
  filecontent =~ /^  JOURNAL  \*?(.*)/
  captured_journal = $1
```

or

```
  /^  JOURNAL  \*?(.*)/.match(filecontent)[1]
```

---

Correction after you posted more details:

You could use the regex `/^\s*JOURNAL\s+(.*)/`. Your Regexp uses a fix number of spaces. With `\s+` the number of spaces is flexible.

Comment: Thank you knut!! Yes it is in a loop and your second suggestion worked really well. Using "unless captured_journal restricted the results to one journal entry but I am getting repeats of the same result two times for my first file and three times for my second file.  Any further suggestions?  Thanks for your help!!!!!!

Comment: Without any code it is impossible to give you an answer. But if you want only *one result* then perhaps the break-solution is better.